# How can I fix comments to the top?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have comments for posts, and want to add a feature such that, if a user clicks the button "Mark as useful", this comment will be fixed at the top of all comments.

I added a boolean value to the comments table, and also added toggle method to switch between `true` and `false` for comments.

How can I fix the comments to the top when the value is `true`, like pinned tweets in twitter?

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.

You can make two queries. One with `userful=true` and second with `useful=false`, thus getting two sets and displaying first useful, then common comments.

Version 2.

You can sort by `useful` column. Depending on database vendor, you might need ascending or descending order (more often descending).

Comment: I also tried do it like this
atop_comments = acomments.where(top: true)

<div class='top comment'>
   <%= render atop_comment %>
</div>

Dosn't work, return nill

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the top column to integer, and for each "Mark as useful" click, to increase top column by 1 (or whatever points you want).
Then you sort comments desc for top. The comment with the more points will be the  first.